# Get Total Seconds In javascript

Tags: javascript, html, eonasdan-datetimepicker

I am using Eonasdan datetimepicker. In formatting date it contains PM and AM and so I love to use it for my date in order to identify time easily. But when I am creating some condition via Javascript to calculate the total seconds of two given times with AM and PM text it alerts `Nan`. What is the best solution to get the total number of seconds with AM and PM text given?

The codes are the following:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var datetime_in= '06/30/2017 7:56 AM';
    var datetime_out= '06/30/2017 5:16 PM';

    var totalseconds= datetime_in - datetime_out;
    alert(totalseconds);
</script>
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```js
var datetime_in = '06/30/2017 7:56 AM';
var datetime_out = '06/30/2017 5:16 PM';

var totalseconds = Math.abs(new Date(datetime_in) - new Date(datetime_out)) / 1000;
alert("The difference is " + totalseconds + " seconds!");
```

Answer (score 3):

Use `getTime()` method.

> Return the number of milliseconds since 1970/01/01

```js
    var datetime_in= '06/30/2017 7:56 AM';
    var datetime_out= '06/30/2017 5:16 PM';

    var date_in = new Date(datetime_in);
    var date_out = new Date(datetime_out);
    
    var seconds = Math.abs(date_out.getTime() - date_in.getTime()) / 1000;
    console.log(seconds);
```

Ref : https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_gettime.asp

Comment: you don't need to use `getTime()` it's automatically used when doing math operations on an Date object

Answer (score 0):

Use JS [Date](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_obj_date.asp) object and use getTime function in it to get val in milliseconds.